# Can not get Type of LinkedList`T with Type.GetType(string)

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am able to get type information of `List<T>`, `Dictinary<TK, TVal>` etc. by:

```
Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]")
Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String[]]")
```

But failing to get type information of `LinkedList<T>`:

```
Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList`1[System.String]") // Returns NULL
Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]") // Also returns NULL
```

Inspecting the assembly of `LinkedList<string>`

```
typeof(LinkedList<decimal>).Assembly
```

Gives:

```
System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

Using .NET Standart 2.0.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify the fully qualified assembly name for `System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList`1` type

```cs
var type = Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList`1[System.String], System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");
```

or just use assembly name

```cs
type = Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList`1[System.String], System");
```

[`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) is part of `mscorlib.dll`, whether [`LinkedList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=netframework-4.8) is part of `System.dll`

You were almost right here

```cs
Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]") // Also returns NULL
```

But you've specified the fully qualified name for generic type parameter, which is `System.String` type, not for `LinkedList`.

Comment: OP: Note that `LinkedList<T>` is in the **System** assembly on .NET Framework but it's in the **System.Collections** assembly on .NET Core.  See [this](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList%3CT%3E). You'll be tied to a specific implementation if you hard-code the assembly name. If you can use `typeof(LinkedList<string>)` instead, you should.

Comment: You are definitely right @madreflection. Getting type information on compile time is straight forward but my challenge is getting type information from user defined string at runtime. PS: I was tried installing `System.Collections` package but failed before your comment. Thank you, your comment helped me too.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, that's because `List<>` is defined in `mscorlib.dll` that is automatically being probed, while `LinkedList<>` is defined in `System.dll` (from the GAC).

Hence, you have to explicitly denote the assembly name when dynamically loading it:

```
Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList`1, System")
```

From the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=netframework-4.8#System_Type_GetType_System_String_):

> If the type is in the currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll,
>   it is sufficient to supply the type name qualified by its namespace.